# Network UNCLAIMED - Unable to access internet

Tags: networking, wifi, drivers, network-interface

My Kubuntu was working well until I think a day ago, and suddenly I don't have access to Wi-Fi. I've tried turning on the connection via the Connection editor but the box was grayed out.
After looking for solutions via various sites i came up with this answer to

```
lshw -c network
```

as following:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHZ
capabilities: bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:f0500000-f050ffff
```

I understood that this problem caused because i lack a driver, but the thing is, everything was working fine about a day ago.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. How did you get the "ath9k" ? I am trying to find out what it would be in my case.

Thanks in advance for your help! from @Inês (originally posted in an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay after searching some more, and focusing on the driver problem i came up with this:

```
  echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
  sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
  sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

I have no idea what it does, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 16.04 and Qualcomm AR9485, the following steps seems to resolve the issue:-

1. First install the linux backports module from the following link:
   http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic_3.2.0.126.141_amd64.deb
2. Run the followig command from terminal

   sudo modprobe ath9k
3. If wifi options are still not listed run:

   sudo service network-manager restart